# ASP.NET Localization - Converting HTML Tags

Tags: asp.net, localization

When I created the "Login.aspx.resx" file, tags like the one below are not listed. Tried to add manually. Didn't work. What's the way to change the text "Giriş Yapın" to "Log In" using Localization? I don't want to use Labels as I have quite a few of these.

```
<h3>Giris Yapın</h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The H3 tag is not an ASP.Net object and so it will not be picked up by the localsation engine. You have already mentioned labels which is one way around it but you may also want to consider the literal tag as that is an ASP.Net object and you can wrap it around the H3 without modifying it directly.
`<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"><h3>Giris Yapın</h3></asp:Literal>`